# Select2 doesn't work when embedded in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

When i use select2 in a popup screen for select countries, i can't text anything into it. The select2 field link a disabled field. But no problem in the selection process. Outside the popup it's works fine.

Comment: add code what you have tied?

Answer (score 0):

> use

`$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".abcclass").select2();
    });`

for better follow these links
[select issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229732/select2-basic-example-not-working) [select bootstrap model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: In normal case it's fine. but in my case the select2 field embedded in a dialog.